# Multiple Matrix Formatting

Tags: matrices, sourcecode

I'm wondering if there's a more cleaner/nicer way to write this equation

```
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[a.)]
\item If $u_i, v_i \in \R $ for $1 \leq i \leq 2 $, then 
        \begin{equation*}
            \vec{u} \oplus \vec{v} = 
            \begin{bmatrix}
                    u_1\\
                    u_2
            \end{bmatrix}
            +
            \begin{bmatrix}
                    v_1\\
                    v_2
            \end{bmatrix}
            =
            \begin{bmatrix}
                    u_1 + v_1\\
                    u_2 + v_2
            \end{bmatrix}
            \in \R^2.
        \end{equation*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

I have about 9 more entries to type up in this list and I don't want my code to be completely unreadable.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please make your code compilable! as small complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. and shortly: your code seems to just fine (beside missing things).

Comment: In particular, \R is undefined.  I suspect you want either \renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi})}% or [label=\alph*)] using  the enumitem package.

Answer (score 2):

I find the following code quite readable. :-)

As you'll notice, I'm not convinced of the benefits of exaggerated nested indentation amounts; naturally, your views may differ. Observe, in addition, the setting up of a macro called `\myvec`, to simplify the use of instances of `bmatrix` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'equation*' and 'bmatrix' environments
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for '\mathbb' macro
\usepackage{enumitem} % to modify enumeration labels
\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand\myvec[1]{\begin{bmatrix} #1 \end{bmatrix}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
\item If $u_i, v_i \in \R$, $1 \le i \le 2$, then
  \begin{equation*}
    \vec{u} \oplus \vec{v} 
    = \myvec{ u_1 \\ u_2 } + \myvec{ v_1 \\ v_2 }
    = \myvec{ u_1 + v_1 \\ u_2 + v_2 }
    \in \R^2\,.
  \end{equation*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Looks much cleaner. Thanks!